# Program analysis of a coin toss simulator

Tags: probability, probabilistic-programming

Here's a problem I'm trying to solve (it's a problem from the CS109 course, assignment 2):

> Suppose we want to write an algorithm `fairRandom` for randomly generating a $0$ or a $1$ with equal probability ($= 0.5$). Unfortunately, all we have available to us is a function: `unknownRandom()` that randomly generates bits, where on each call a $1$ is returned with some unknown probability $p$ that need not be equal to $0.5$ (and a $0$ is returned with probability $1–p$). Consider the following algorithm for `fairRandom`:

```
def fairRandom():
    while True:
        r1 = unknownRandom()
        r2 = unknownRandom()
        if (r1 != r2): break
    return r2
```

> a) Show mathematically that `fairRandom` does indeed return a $0$ or $1$ with equal probability.
>
> b) Say we want to simplify the function, so we write the `simpleRandom` function below. Would this also generate $0$ and $1$ with equal probability? Determine $P($`simpleRandom`$\text{ returns } 1)$ in terms of $p$.

```
def simpleRandom():
    r1 = unknownRandom()
    while True:
        r2 = unknownRandom()
        if (r1 != r2): break
        r1 = r2
    return r2
```

---

**My attempt**:

a) Let the number of loops be denoted by $L$. Then
$$P(r_2=1)=P(r_2=1,L=1)+P(r_2=1,L=2)+P(r_2=1,L=3)+\ldots
\\=(1-p)p+[p^2+(1-p)^2](1-p)p+[p^2+(1-p)^2]^2(1-p)p+\ldots$$

since if $L=n$, then for $n-1$ loops either both $r_1=r_2=0$ or $r_1=r_2=1$, thereby giving $[p^2+(1-p)^2]^{n-1}$ and in the last loop, $r_1=0$ and $r_2=1$, giving a probability of $(1-p)p$. The above expression further simplifies to:

$$(1-p)p\big[1+[p^2+(1-p)^2]+[p^2+(1-p)^2]^2+\ldots\big]
\\=\frac{p(1-p)}{1-p^2-(1-p)^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Similarly for $P(r_2=0)$.

---

b) The line `r1 = r2` is redundant, since that's run only if $r_1$ is already equal to $r_2$ (otherwise the loop would break in the previous statement). So basically the loop is run till the generated value for $r_2$ is different from the initial value of $r_1$.

If initially $r_1=1$, then the final value of $r_2$ would have to be $0$, so in that case, $P(r_2=1\ |\ \text{init }r_1=1)=0$. But if initially $r_1=0$, then $r_2$ will surely be $1$. So $$P(r_2=1)=P(r_2=1\ |\ \text{init }r_1=0)P(\text{init }r_1=0)=1\times(1-p)=1-p$$

I'm not too sure about either part. Are these correct? Would be grateful for feedback.

Comment: Your claim in (b) about a redundant statement is not correct.  As far as the first part of the problem goes, there's a much simpler solution: just compute $\Pr(r_2=1\mid r_1\ne r_2).$

Comment: @whuber: In (b), let's say $r_1=1$ initially. If $r_2=1$, then the `r1 != r2` condition is not satisfied and the loop continues. `r1 = r2` assigns $1$ to $r_1$ and we're back to where we started. If, at any point, `r2` gets allocated $0$ value, the loop breaks (since the value of $r_1$ always remains $1$). But the loop breaks only when $r_2=0$ (in the scenario when initial value of $r_1=1$).

Comment: That does not make the test redundant--but it does reveal the problem with the algorithm.

Comment: @whuber: For sure the test (if condition) isn't redundant. I don't know if that's how the function was supposed to be, because $r_1$ doesn't change from its initial value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fairRandom we have
$ \begin{cases}
P(r_1=0, r_2=0) & (1-p)^2 \\ 
P(r_1=0, r_2=1) & p-p^2 \\ 
P(r_1=1, r_2=0) & p-p^2 \\ 
P(r_1=1, r_2=1) & p^2 
\end{cases}$ since we only return for $P(r_1=0, r_2=1)$ and $P(r_1=1, r_2=0)$ and they have the same probability, it should be obvious $p=0.5$.

For b) note that the probabilities of $P(r_1=0, r_2=1)$ and $P(r_1=1, r_2=0)$ are not the same after the first loop because the probability of $P(r_1)$ has changed.

Edit: While commuting to stats class I realized OP was correct for part b). $r_1$ never changes in simpleRandom: because the line r1 = r2 only executes if $r_1$ is already equal to $r_2$. This means simpleRandom: merely returns the inverse of $r_1$ and thus has probability of $1 - p$.

This is some R code I generated to explore the problem numerically:

```
unknownRandom <- function(){
  return(runif(1) < 0.2) # here our unknown p = 0.2
}

fairRandom <- function(){
  r2<-numeric(0)
  while(1){
    r1 = unknownRandom()
    r2 = unknownRandom()
    if (r1 != r2){break}
  }
  return(r2)
}

simpleRandom <- function(){
  r1 <- unknownRandom()
  while(1){
    r2 <- unknownRandom()
    if (r1 != r2){break}
    r1 <- r2
  }
  return(r2)
}

fres <- numeric(0)
sres <- numeric(0)
niter<-1e5
for(i in 1:niter)
{
  fres[i] <- fairRandom()
  sres[i] <- simpleRandom()
}

sum(fres)/niter # prints approx 0.5
sum(sres)/niter # prints approx 0.8 (or 1-p)
```